# Should Gentoo's Hardened profile / SELinux be used on normal desktop computers?

Tags: linux, security, gentoo, selinux

well, the title pretty much says everything. I'm installing Gentoo on my machine, and I'm wondering whether I should use SELinux or not for a desktop computer. I'd also like to know if there are any important implications I should know about (like performance, for example).

Thanks,
Julian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gentoo Hardened profiles are usable on workstations, even the SELinux profiles. However, you must be aware that SELinux is an advanced mandatory access control mechanism that requires you, as the administrator of the system, to learn about it a bit. When SELinux is prohibiting processes to do stuff, you should be able to deduce what the application is doing and allow (or dismiss) the activity.

On http://hardened.gentoo.org/selinux you'll find more information about SELinux with Gentoo Hardened.